# Amazon S3 Multipart Upload Async

Tags: asynchronous, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multipartform-data

I'm working with Amazon S3 multipart uploading and I read that you can upload parts of a file in parallel. However, looking through documentation I see that Amazon's response to an uploaded file part does not contain a part number. So my question is if I upload Part 1 of a file and Part 2 of a file asynchronously then I check for a response from Amazon how do I know if the response is referring to Part 1 or Part 2 of the file?

Here's an example request and response.

```
Request:
PUT /my-movie.m2ts?partNumber=1&uploadId=VCVsb2FkIElEIGZvciBlbZZpbmcncyBteS1tb3ZpZS5tMnRzIHVwbG9hZR HTTP/1.1
Host: example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
Date:  Mon, 1 Nov 2010 20:34:56 GMT
Content-Length: 10485760
Content-MD5: pUNXr/BjKK5G2UKvaRRrOA==
Authorization: AWS AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE:VGhpcyBtZXNzYWdlIHNpZ25lZGGieSRlbHZpbmc=

***part data omitted***

Response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: Vvag1LuByRx9e6j5Onimru9pO4ZVKnJ2Qz7/C1NPcfTWAtRPfTaOFg==
x-amz-request-id: 656c76696e6727732072657175657374
Date:  Mon, 1 Nov 2010 20:34:56 GMT
ETag: "b54357faf0632cce46e942fa68356b38"
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Server: AmazonS3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Etag you get back in the response to each part is the md5sum of the part you just uploaded.

In the case of your example, unless I have made an error, your Content-MD5 decodes to a54357aff06328ae46d942af69146b38 ... so I would suggest that unless you have a problem with your MD5 calculation, the request and the response you've posted don't actually belong together.

The multipart uploader that I wrote is *extremely* pedantic because I use it to archive critical data (so pedantic, in fact, that it actually turns around and re-downloads the file after it thinks the multipart upload succeeded to be absolutely certain that the final product is perfect) ... but this utility submits the parts sequentially with a call that blocks and doesn't return until the response comes back... and one of its sanity tests is to compare the locally-calculated MD5 of the block with the Etag returned, and it's a fatal error if they don't match... so unless you have identical blocks, it would seem like you could correlate the parts that way.

---

additional:

I didn't use the missing body to calculate an md5 :) I took your header:

```
Content-MD5: pUNXr/BjKK5G2UKvaRRrOA==
```

Converted from base64 -> binary -> hex and got a54357aff06328ae46d942af69146b38.

I do my verification downloads by stringing together 2 command line utilities, like this:

```
wget --server-response '$signed_url' -O - | md5sum
```

This downloads the file and pipes the bytes into md5sum for calculating the checksum, so I can download an infinitely-large file without using any disk space and very little memory.  The `wget` utility has built-in retrying capability and will try to continue from the byte position where it left off if something breaks the connection.  The outputs of this pipeline are the md5sum of the file (stdout) and the headers sent by the server and a progress meter (stderr).  My utility captures stdout and does the comparison, while letting stderr leak through to the console for observation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I actually just found out that the ETag is the MD5 yesterday by looking through some forums. I was unaware of that before. This should work to figure out which part the response is referring to, hopefully I won't get any collisions. It seems to me that it would have been a better design for Amazon to send the part number back in the response.

Comment: Also one more question for downloading the file I am looking for an efficient way to download large files from Amazon so far I am thinking to use the HTTP range header and request chunks of the file at a time so if there is an interruption I can continue downloading from where I left off. Did you find any speed ups for downloading large files? Thanks again.

Comment: Oh and as for the example above the MD5 doesn't work out because the message body was left out intentionally "***part data omitted***". It was just for reference.

Comment: I updated the answer... but it seems like your http library should be able to correlate responses to requests somehow... it's hard to imagine it being really useful otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

When you initiate the multipart upload, you include the part number in the request. [From the AWS multipart upload documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadUploadPart.html):

```
PUT /ObjectName?partNumber=PartNumber&uploadId=UploadId HTTP/1.1
Host: BucketName.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: date
Content-Length: Size
Authorization: Signature
```

Therefore there's no ambiguity about which part you have just uploaded.

**EDIT** So the basic process is the following:

1. Initiate a multipart upload and get an UploadId
2. Upload all the parts
   in parallel. In each response you will get an ETag header - you need
   to remember it and the part number it goes with so AWS can
   reassemble the file
3. Then send all the ETag values and the part
   numbers and complete the multipart upload

Comment: Thanks for your response I know which part I have uploaded but if I am uploading two parts at the same time then I receive a response from Amazon I have no way to tell whether the response is acknowledging Part 1 or Part 2. At least I don't see a way to tell which response is for which part of the file.

Comment: Ok I still understand all of that. But for part 2 above how do you know which part number the ETag goes with. For example part 1 is 5MB and part 2 is only 2KB am I guaranteed to receive the response for Part 1 first?

Comment: Each request has a corresponding response from AWS. It's HTTP - a request will either timeout or succeed or fail (and a response will come back for those last two). No they're not guaranteed to respond back in the same order the requests were initiated in - but each part being uploaded doesn't have awareness of the other parts so it doesn't matter. It might help me explain better help if you included some details about how you are performing the upload - is it through the command-line tools? Through JavaScript in a web browser?

Comment: I am using C++ with an asynchronous socket connection to Amazon S3 and using an IO Completion Port. I am using only one socket for all the requests and responses. So if I send two parts of a file at the same time one 5MB and one 2KB obviously the 2KB part will be much faster to send and will finish much more quickly then the previous part. When I receive my response from the IO Completion Port I am unsure whether this response is for Part 1 or Part 2 I can assume that the smaller part sent faster but this is not a safe assumption.